# Can someone show how to use a hashmap and reverse for loop is better then addition and subtraction in a program like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, hashmap, roman-numerals

I found a Leet code problem which involved converting a string of Roman Numerals to Normal Integers and a friend of mine told me that using a ** Hashmap and a reverse for loop ** is best in an issue like this, although using simple arithmetic operations, I solved the problem.

Can someone explain how it works better in that scenario?
Thank you in advance.

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        answer = 0

        answer = (s.count('M') * 1000) + (s.count('C') * 100) + (s.count('X') * 10) + (s.count('I') * 1)
        answer += (s.count('D') * 500) + (s.count('L') * 50) + (s.count('V') * 5)

        answer -= (s.count('CM') * 200) + (s.count('XC') * 20) + (s.count('IX') * 2)
        answer -= (s.count('CD') * 200) + (s.count('XL') * 20) + (s.count('IV') * 2)

        return answer
```

Comment: Your solution is quite inefficient. `count` walks the entire `s` each time, so your code iterates the entirety of `s` 13 times.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was thinking in a proper scenario, will a HashMap run through the program once while collecting all data?

Comment: Yes. It would be far more efficient to iterate `s` once, build up all the counts, then iterate the hashmap once (which doesn't depend on the length of `s`) and sum the counts. Or just iterate `s` and do the math as you go if that's workable.

Comment: Hmm, why aren't you asking that friend who made the claim?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think walking the entire `s` makes it slow. At least not when counting single characters, that takes like a nanosecond per character, at least for long strings. The function call overhead probably takes much more time

Comment: @KellyBundy it was some random guy on discord who told me that, I say friend because its needless to say on this platform, and the person didnt provide a reason either